# Using scanner in multiple classes

Tags: java

I just started learning Java and wrote this code to practice creating interface. I realize that the use of the interface relation here is probably not how it's supposed to be actually used but I was doing this only for practice and basic understanding.

So anyways, I created the program to take user input on what operation they'd like to perform and then carry out said operation. For this purpose, the user provides two inputs: first the operation that they'd like performed and then a number on which they would like it performed. So for example if they would like to find the square root of 4 they'd first enter 2 to select square root and then 4 to indicate they'd like to find the square root of 4. So for this purpose, I opened the scanner class on multiple classes. However, closing the scanner in any one of the classes creates an error because apparently once you close it in a file it cannot be reopened. I searched a lot and most suggestions were centered around saying that using multiple instances of scanner like this just creates problems so create only one. While I can rewrite this code to make that adjustment, I was wondering if there was a way that I could do what I have done without creating any warning messages like they pop up in this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1. Square");
        System.out.println("2. Square Root");
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        int choice = in.nextInt();

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
        Squaring s1 = new Squaring();
        s1.getDim();
        s1.operate();
        break;

        case 2:
        Root r1 = new Root();
        r1.getDim();
        r1.operate();
        }
    }
}

interface Method
{
    void getDim();
    void operate();
}

class Squaring implements Method
{
    double n, r;

    public void getDim()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input Number: ");
        n = in.nextDouble();
    }

    public void operate()
    {
        r = n*n;
        System.out.println("Squared of " + n + " is = " + r);
    }
}

class Root implements Method
{
    double n, r;

    public void getDim()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input Number: ");
        n = in.nextDouble();
        in.close();
    }

    public void operate()
    {
        r = Math.sqrt(n);
        System.out.println("Square root of " + n + " is = " + r);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't show any warning/error. It works just fine. What else do you want?

Answer (score 1):

The warning popups my IDE (Netbeans) shows are for the Override annotation and the Scanner objects you instantiate.
Your code could look like this if you want to eliminate the warnings:

```
class Squaring implements Method
{
     double n, r;

     @Override
     public void getDim()
     {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Input Number: ");
            n = in.nextDouble();
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void operate()
     {
         r = n*n;
         System.out.println("Squared of " + n + " is = " + r);
     }
}
```

The override annotation is used because you are overriding this method because of the interface each class (Squaring and Root) is implementing.

Also the try clause i added is something you will learn later (you are still a junior but it is basic to know that) and has to do with exception/error handling.

---

To avoid having errors while closing the Scanner object try this:

- Create a class, lets say the MyStatics class.
- Constructor is not needed. Add this as an object:

  `public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`
- Call the scan object from any class you want by using this example:

  `String input = MyStatics.scan.nextLine();`
- Close the scanner object at the end of the excecution of the program.

I hope this will solve all the issues you are facing in your code.